# Opening or creating file in Office Web Apps gives a screen full of gibberish

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

We seem to have developed an odd issue today- whenever we try to create or edit an office document from SharePoint we get a screen covered in gibberish, with just the occasional bit of layout or content.
This has persisted across a restart of both the webapp and SharePoint servers. The files are fine when edited in Office client apps on the PC.
I'm not hugely familiar with SharePoint logs and can't see anything immediately obvious in them- has anyone seen similar before?
[image]

Comment: Looks like the CSS is missing - have you checked your browser for errors (404, etc.)

Comment: Cheers Mx- that opened up a useful line of inquiry- we do indeed get "net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED" when the viewer is called from the Office Web App server- now to try and figure out why...

Comment: Glad I could help - btw when you see this kind of mashed up images its mostly sprites with missing CSS

Comment: Any update on this? We are seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

We have figured out that the problem was related to Citrix NetScaler Compression. We turned of compression, cleared the cache and everything works normally. It seems to be a known issue NetScaler 11, Build 67.12.

> See issue 629128
>
> https://www.citrix.com/content/dam/citrix/en_us/documents/downloads/netscaler-adc/NS_11_0_67_12.html
>
> > **Acceleration**
> >
> > If a compression module receives an HTTP header in two NetScaler Buffers (NSBs), where first the NSB has a complete header ending with "\r\n\r" and the other NSB header ending with "\n", the module does not handle the HTTP header properly. This results in garbled page rendering at client-side browser.